# How can I use a while loop with an if statement in python?

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to write a script that takes in a character (M) OR (F) and returns output as male OR female. I was wondering how I could do this with a while loop. What I have currently is if statements which do not loop back.

```
gender = input('What is your gender? M/F: ').capitalize()
mGender = ''
if gender == 'M':
   mGender = 'Male'
elif gender == 'F':
   mGender = 'Female'
else:
   #how do I go back to make sure only F/f or M/m were input by the user?
```

Comment: ...in the end the output should be either male or female; print ( 'Your gender is ' + mGender)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do when user input M/m or F/f program display male/female. If you enter any other character system should display "please enter gender again message" and user asked again what is your gender. You can try this

```
gender = input('What is your gender? M/F: ').capitalize()
mGender = ''

while gender != 'M' or gender != 'F':
    if gender == 'M':
        mGender = 'Male'
        break;
    elif gender == 'F':
        mGender = 'Female'
        break;
    else:
        print("Wrong input please enter gender again")
        print()
        gender = input('What is your gender? M/F: ').capitalize()

print('Your gender is = ' +mGender)
```

In this code If you enter wrong character system ask your gender again and again until you enter M/m or F/f.

Comment: Worked like a charm, this does help to shed light on my own understanding of while loops. Thank you